# sqlalchemy - select from partition

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, database-partitioning

I have the following query (mysql):

```
SELECT *
FROM people PARTITION (p202108, p202109)
WHERE city='new york'
```

here it is in my python code - using sqlalchemy, but I didn't find how to add the partitions

```
res = People.query.filter(People.city = 'new york').all()
```

how can I add the partitions to the query?